# Netty 4.0 Channel Local

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 4(alpha8).

I want to share some data between ChannelHanders in a pipeline, in previous versions of Netty I think I would have used a ChannelLocal, is there a Netty 4 equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer shortly after I posted my question.

I need to use the attribute map available on the Channel:

http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy.html